# MongoDB sort by property in other document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, json-api

In order to expand the JSON-API capabilities of my `node.js` application, I'm trying to sort a query based on relationships (AKA other documents), although I don't want to return them.

According to the [JSON-API documentation](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-sorting):

> a sort field of `author.name` could be used to request that the primary data be sorted based upon the `name` attribute of the `author` relationship.

E.g. `db.collection('books').find({})` returns:

```
[
    {
        type: "book",
        id: "2349",
        attributes: {
            title: "My Sweet Book"
        },
        relationships: {
            author: {
                data: {
                    type: "authors",
                    id: "9"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {} // etc ...
]
```

`db.collection('authors').find({id: "9"})` returns:

```
[
    {
        type: "author",
        id: "9",
        attributes: {
            name: "Hank Moody"
        }
    }
]
```

Now I need some way to do something similar to e.g.:
`db.collection('books').find({}).sort({"author.name": -1})`

I think I need to convert the query to an aggregation so I can use the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operator, but I'm not sure how to use `localField` and `foreignField`.

```
db.collection('books').aggregate([
    {$match: {}},
    {$lookup: {from: "authors", localField: "attributes.author.data.id", foreignField: "id", as: "temp.author"}},
    {$sort: {"$books.temp.author.name": -1}},
    {$project: {temp: false}},
])
```

**Notes**

- This will be a global function for fetching JSON-API data.

  - This means **we don't know** wether a sort key is an `attribute` or a `relationship`.
- Most servers run LTS versions and have **MongoDB 3.2**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try below aggregation.

`$lookup` to join to `authors` collection followed by `$unwind` to flatten the `book_author` array for applying `$sort` on `name` field and `$project` with exclusion to remove `book_author` field ( only works starting Mongo 3.4 version ). For lower versions you have to include all the other fields you want to keep and excluding `book_author` field in the `$project` stage.

```
 db.collection('books').aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "authors",
        localField: "relationships.author.data.id",
        foreignField: "id",
        as: "book_author"
    }
 }, {
    $unwind: "$book_author"
 }, {
    $sort: {
        "book_author.attributes.name": -1
    }
 }, {
    $project: {
        "book_author": 0
    }
 }])
```

Comment: Looks promising. Upvoted for now. Can we (1) `$unwind` up to a point (of 1 in this case)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't not understand your comment for `$unwind`. For the edit mentioned in the post, you can add a field in the `$project` stage, something like  `sortkey: { $ifNull: [ "$attribute", "relationship" ] }` after `$unwind` stage followed by `$sort` with  `"sortkey": -1`. Let me know what you think.

Comment: _"Sorry, I didn't not understand your comment for $unwind"_

Can we `$unwind` only the first _n_ entries of an array?

Comment: No we cant because `$unwind` takes the field path not expression. You can add a `$project` stage before `$unwind` with `$slice` to pick first `n` elements. Something like `{$project:{"book_author":{"$slice":["$book_author", n"]}}}`